# Vaadin sum calculation

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, primavera

[image]

I am not able to add the fields, I have already tried several modifications in the code, but nothing worked.

My current code is this for the sum of the fields:

```
txtAmount.addValueChangeListener(event -> {

            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
            double totalValue= 0;

            try {
                totalValue = formatter.parse(txtUnitaryValue.getValue()).doubleValue() * txtQuantidade.getValue();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            txtTotalItemValue.setValue(formatter.format(totalValue));

            addValues= totalValue;
            fieldAddsValues.setValue(formatter.format(addValues));

        });
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Try extracting both the number values into separate variables before multiplying them so it's easier to inspect their values with the debugger.

Comment: Marcus, I don't get any exceptions ...

Sorry, but I'm new to Vaadin / Java ... how could I do that?

Comment: Twistleton, I understand, but it takes away a doubt, in part of my current code, should I put this example that you gave me? And yes, Double

Comment: my complete code below

Comment: haha Portuguese...Brazil

Comment: where do i put your code ??

Comment: it worked, friend ... thank you very much for your help, if you want to post the code, mark it as the correct answer for you ... thank you very much !!!

Comment: By the way, for money matters you should be using `BigDecimal` rather than floating-point types float/Float/double/Double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the sum of all positions set this snippet in the txtAmount.addValueChangeListener block:

```
Double sum = listaVendas.stream().mapToDouble(product -> product.getPrice() * product.getQuantity()).sum();
```